# How to send event or message to external process in Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, postmessage

In Windows I can post custom message to another process and inform it to do an action like:

```
PostMessage(WindowOfAnyProcess, WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, param1, param2)
```

What is the alternative on Mac OS? Does Carbon Events help me? How?
Thankyou.

Comment: I dont know any of that help me or not, I do not want use solutions based on networking or need some configurations or need sudo command and ..., probably I should use shared memory approach.

Comment: Are you taking to another app you are creating?  Or do you want to talk to a third-party app?

Comment: both apps are mine. not third-party.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that both of the processes are yours, you can use [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to send notifications and data to each process.

To do this do something like:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HelloFromProcessOne" object:nil]
```

If you want to include data you can use:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HelloFromProcessOne" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"some info here" forKey:@"data"]]
```

**A note should be added that:** 
Sandboxed apps can send notifications only if they do not contain a dictionary. If the sending application is in an App Sandbox, `notificationInfo` must be `nil`. This means that you won't be able to provide information with the notification if you intend on targeting the Mac AppStore.

To make the application receive the notifications do something like:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someNotificationUpdate:) name:@"HelloFromProcessOne" object:nil]
```

`someNotificationUpdate:` would be declared like:

```
- (void)someNotificationUpdate:(NSNotification *)note;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Which process receive notification? no destination process id specified in postNotificationName. and destination process how receives this notification?

Comment: The notification will be sent to any object (in any process) that registers itself to receive them. You could specify the object but I find that using nil is just easier. I updated the code above to show how to receive notifications.

Comment: This kind of notifications are "system wide"; one object posts, and zero or more objects listen. It's not a one-to-one pipe like in Windows; it's more like a radio broadcast. There is also an NSNoticationCenter class that does the same but only within your app (no inter-process communication)

Comment: Thank you nosedive for your help.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But is there any alternative (to NSDistributedNotificationCenter) that allows for sending notification with dictionary from a sandboxed app.